# lambda meaning on the expression $λA+(1−λ)B$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-analysis

I was reading an article regarding a convex function and my question is regarding the meaning of the following definition. $λA+(1−λ)B$. I have seen this in different places. In one of them it was referred as the general form of a line which I did not understand well. It is found in this question: [How to get Point between two points at any specific distance?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155514/how-to-get-point-between-two-points-at-any-specific-distance). In the example he had two points: $Point A=(50,150); Point B=(150,50)$ and he defined this equality $λA+(1−λ)B=(150−100λ,50+100λ)$ which I really don't understand why is it. I would like to have a better understanding of what is the meaning of this expression $λA+(1−λ)B$ and why he expressed the two points in that way. I hope I am clear with my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write $$\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B=B+\lambda(A-B)$$

When $\lambda=0$, you are at $B$.

When $\lambda=1$, you are at $A$.

when $\lambda$ increases, you are moving from B towards $A$ along the direction of $A-B$.

Comment: One last question, what does A and B represent, are they a point on space or just a number?

Comment: You can view them as points on space.